# How to un-standardize PCA reconstructions using StandardScaler inverse?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am trying to run a PCA analysis on ocean temperature data using sklearn. First I use StandardScaler to standardize the data, then I run the PCA and create the reconstructions. I can get code to work fine up until that point. However, I cannot figure out how to apply the inverse of the StandardScaler back to the PCA reconstructions so that they are back in the original space and I can compare the reconstructions to the original unstandardized data. I've copied a short excerpt of the code I'm using below, along with the error I receive below it. None of the potential fixes I've found online have actually worked.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = array[:,[1,4]] # data has dimensions [88 (depths) x 26 (instances)]
        
# pre processing the data
scal = StandardScaler()   
data_t = scal.fit_transform(data)
    
  
# pca analysis
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents_2 = pca.fit_transform(np.transpose(data_t))  #find the loadings.
PCAFit_2 = scal.inverse_transform(pca.inverse_transform(principalComponents_2)) #reconstruct the data and then apply the standardscaler inverse tranformation.
```

Error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (26,88) (26,) (26,88)
```

Comment: Since PCA is making new variable values that maximize the variance across the independent axes, you cannot use the same instance of StandardScaler to accurately inverse the scaling process. That being said, I'm not sure if there is a proper solution to this problem. However, if you give me any additional information as to what you are  going to be looking for when you compare the PCA construction with the original data, we might be able to circumvent the problen entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X, _ = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

pca = PCA(2)
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_scaled)

X_orig = np.dot(X_pca, pca.components_)
X_orig_backscaled = scaler.inverse_transform(X_orig)

print("                    Original:", X[0])
print("                      Scaled:", X_scaled[0])
print("                   PCA space:", X_pca[0])
print("           Original from PCA:", X_orig[0])
print("Original from PCA backscaled:", X_orig_backscaled[0])
```

---

```
                    Original: [5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
                      Scaled: [-0.90068117  1.01900435 -1.34022653 -1.3154443 ]
                   PCA space: [-2.26470281  0.4800266 ]
           Original from PCA: [-0.99888895  1.05319838 -1.30270654 -1.24709825]
Original from PCA backscaled: [5.01894899 3.51485426 1.46601281 0.25192199]
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergey! This is very helpful, and my script works when I apply this methodology. I have two followup questions: 1) Where is the pca.inverse_transform step here? Is that simply what the X_orig line is doing? and 2) How do I obtain the actual principal component values that are being used to reconstruct my data.   Can I simply use "pca.components_" to find these values ? Many thanks.

Comment: PCA inverse transform is `np.dot(X_pca, pca.components_)`.